# Deleted .ecryptfs but system still running - any hopes?

Tags: mount, encryption, ecryptfs

I believe I have deleted my .ecryptfs passphrase files (~/.ecryptfs/ is empty) but that computer still is online with its drives mounted. I'm currently trying to recover the lost files with r-linux and will try creating a backup of my important files on a network drive but I'm essentially wondering:

Is there a way to regenerate my .ecryptfs passphrase whilst the computer still is running? I did not take note of the original passphrase, I only have my login password.

Comment: I know if a file is still in use or "opened" by some program/process, it's not really deleted and still exists - I've had to hunt down processes that kept me from really deleting a file using `lsof` - so maybe any .ecryptfs files are still listed in `lsof`, and you can copy/move/undelete them? I don't know offhand the method to do that though

Comment: I did a quick lsof | grep -i pass this morning and (the machine is still on) it didn't return anything useful unfortunately.

Comment: hmmm... another idea - the keys may still be in the kernel keyring. Try taking a look with `keyctl show` or maybe `sudo keyctl show`, if there are some in there, at least you could copy them to a file (man or maybe info keyctl should say how to get the actual key out)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might still have some .ecryptfs files still opened by some process, in which case they might not be really deleted yet. If they're listed in `lsof` you might still be able to copy/move them back. Especially look for the `wrapped-passphrase` file.

The best solution would be if you have a backup copy of your entire home, including the `wrapped-passphrase` file. If all the files were deleted then they may have been overwritten already, and losing the login key, wrapped-passphrase file, and mount key would mean they're locked forever too. Having a copy of the actual mount key would be helpful if the files are still there to read.

---

Or, if the eCryptfs folder is still mounted, the key might be in the kernel keyring still. Take a look with

```
$ keyctl show
Session Keyring
 802145592 --alswrv    999 65534  keyring: _uid_ses.999
 542975566 --alswrv    999 65534   \_ keyring: _uid.999
 414895587 --alswrv    999   999       \_ user: 1848e1d7b8a187fc
 245849561 --alswrv    999   999       \_ user: 554c7c95a5b5d6ee
```

And you might see 1 (no fnek) or 2 (with fnek) entires like the last 2 above. The "1848e1d7b8a187fc" part should match the signature of the mount or fnek sig used by eCryptfs. You could read the key(s) with

- `keyctl read 414895587` - "read" prints it on stdout as a hex dump
- `keyctl print 414895587` - "print" dumps it to stdout directly  if  it's entirely printable or as a hexdump preceded by ":hex:" if not
- `keyctl pipe 414895587 > piped-keyfile` - "pipe" dumps the raw data to stdout

(replace the numbers with the first part of the relevant line from the `keyctl show` output above)

If you extracted it with pipe, then later this command should add the key back into the keyring:

```
cat piped-keyfile | keyctl padd user keydescription @u
```

To match the format of `ecryptfs-add-passphrase` I think changing the keydescription back to the 16 character signature to match the original `keyctl show` output should work.

---

A file undelete program may be able to recover the recently deleted file, if it hasn't been overwritten yet. Programs vary by the filesystem you want to recover files on, or try [`testdisk`](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk) (in [Ubuntu universe repos](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=testdisk)) has excellent luck recovering deleted files from all sorts of filesystems. It's sister program `photorec` could search all the free space of the drive and attempt to recover files too, though I don't know if "ecryptfs wrapped-passphrase" is a filetype it knows.

Comment: It turns out I had an integral disk backup (dd) from a few weeks ago, I was able to recover the required files (/home/.ecryptfs/$USER/.ecryptfs/* - not ~/.ecryptfs as I had originally described). With your method I was able to export keys from my running system but upon recovery of my keys I turned out that the keys I had extracted did not contain the same data (the proper key files were around 17 characters in hexadecimal whereas the exported keys had 711 characters - with seemingly no match). I'm marking this as resolved since this is still a great answer - thanks.

Comment: A Backup is definitely the best. I did test the keyctl extracted key against the `ecryptfs-insert-wrapped-passphrase-into-keyring` tool, it appears to work. But I'm not exactly sure of the relationship between the master passphrase and the keyctl stored key(s), could be a different saved format, or ecryptfs does some work on the master passphrase before using it.